# SDWebImageDownloader reports "incompatible block types" error

Tags: objective-c, sdwebimage

When I add SDWebImage with following code:

```
[[SDWebImageDownloader sharedDownloader] downloadImageWithURL:imageUrl options:0   progress:^(NSUInteger receivedSize, NSInteger expectedSize) {

} completed:^(UIImage *image, NSData *data, NSError *error, BOOL finished) {
    if (image && finished) {
        iconimage.image = image;
    }
}];
```

It reports an error info at line:

```
[[SDWebImageDownloader sharedDownloader] downloadImageWithURL:imageUrl options:0 progress:^(NSUInteger receivedSize, NSInteger expectedSize)
```

The error says:

> incompatible block types sending `'void(^) (NSUInteger, NSInteger)'`  to parameter of type `'SDWebImageDownloaderProgressBlock'` (aka `'void(^)(NSUInteger, NSUInteger)'`)

I am using version 3.6 of SDWebImage.

Comment: I try set the progress nil, it will work.

Answer (score 4):

I just checked the [current SDWebImage source](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/blob/master/SDWebImage/SDWebImageDownloader.h), and the `SDWebImageDownloaderProgressBlock` appears to take two `NSInteger` parameters (note, not `NSUInteger`):

```
typedef void(^SDWebImageDownloaderProgressBlock)(NSInteger receivedSize, NSInteger expectedSize);
```

You are currently using `NSUInteger` for the `receivedSize` parameter and `NSInteger` for `expectedSize`. If the above `typedef` is correct, you should use `NSInteger` for both.

Having said that, you provided an error message, though, suggests that your current copy of SDWebImage is looking for two `NSUInteger` parameters. Perhaps you're using a different version/fork of SDWebImage; perhaps it was just a typo when you entered the error message in your question. Anyway, if your error message really says that it's expecting two `NSUInteger` parameters, then that's what you should use.

Bottom line, you should just ensure that the individual parameters for the `progress` block of `downloadImageWithURL` to exactly match the definition of the `SDWebImageDownloaderProgressBlock` in `SDWebImageDownloader.h`.